# NodeJS get only value of MongoDB result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get only the value of a specific MongoDB field, and have the following code:

```
var collection = db.collection('people');

collection.find({"name" : "John" }, { phone : 1, _id : 0 }).toArray(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else if (result.length) {
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        socket.emit("No documents found");
    };
});
```

This works great however it gives me the following result:

```
[ { phone: 112233 } ]
```

How can I edit the query so that it will return only "112233", or how can I split the array "phone: 112233" so that it will give me the value only?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I tried forEach and MongoDB aggregate, to no avail as of the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split it like this:

```
result[0].phone
```

Comment: Oh wow, I made a shameful amount of tries and in the end it turns out to be so simple. Not sure who downvoted you, however this is the correct answer. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I made a snarky comment at first. I started Seriously?  Don't worry about it.

Comment: Haha I noticed - it doesn't reflect the edits in the notification history. It's okay though, it was a lame question anyway (in hindsight).